# How to get sonarcloud running on Travis Ci with Python code

Tags: python, travis-ci, sonarcloud

My question is rather simple:

How to insert Python Code on SonarCloud with Travis-Ci?

I made the previous steps:

- Create a project in Github
- Assign that project in Travis-Ci
- Create a new project analysis on SonarCloud and get the Token
- Set up the SONAR_TOKEN as not visible and put the Token given by SonarCloud
- In .travis.yml, add in the *scripts* section, the next code:

  ```
  script:
    - python setup.py test
    - ... (other possible commands)
    - sonar-scanner
  ```

But, when I commit something, Travis still stops me with the next job log:
[image: This is the log]

I searched why on Earth this is possible, because Travis says it has sonar-scanner capabilites.

Thanks in advance and have a great day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must declare sonar-scanner as plugin first in .travis.yml

```
addons:
  sonarcloud:
    organization: "sonarcloud_organization_key" # the key of the org you chose at step #3
    token:
      secure: ********* # encrypted value of your token
script:
  # other script steps might be done before running the actual analysis
  - sonar-scanner
```

from https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/sonarcloud/

Comment: The Token has been given as Environment Variables in the Travis-Ci page. It is necessary to put there?

Comment: Well, it seems so, as it isn't working :) I've always used it like in my answer and never had problem

Comment: Also, you must declare runner what is sonar-scanner in order for it to look for its configuration

Comment: You must put
`- sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=PROYECT_KEY -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.organization=USERNAME_GITHUB-github`
In the _script_ zone

Or create a sonar-project.properties with the parameters explained here:
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner